# Создать cookie и записать эти же данные в БД

Tags: php, cookie

При посещении сайта в базу записывается информация об этом посещении, в том числе, уникальный `id` пользователя, который хранится в куки. Если  пользователь ранее уже посещал этот сайт и `id` у него уже хранится  в куки, то все нормально записывается БД. Если же пользователь первый раз на сайте и куки только создается в момент этого посещения, то в БД этот `id` не запишется. Подскажите, пожалуйста, причины, по которым это может происходить.

Comment: а что мешает записать данные в БД до создания куки?

Comment: Одна из возможных причин - хочется сохранить в БД только пользователей, которые зашли на сайт больше одного раза.

Comment: ну код хотябы в студию

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понимаю, у Вас есть нечто, берущее `id` из куки и записывающее его в бд.
В случае, если `id` в куки нет, Вы делаете так (в одно дейтсвие): создать `id` -> записать его в куки -> взять его из куки и записать в БД.
Решение очевидно: в случае, если куки еще не создан, не пытаться брать данные для БД из куки, а брать их от туда, где создается `id` пользователя.

Comment: В общем все просто, причины можно узнать всего лишь почитав описание функции setcookie: "..куки будут невидимы до тех пор, пока не будет загружена следующая страница."

В решение да, как и предлагали тут, оперировать в дальнейшем той переменной в которой и создается новый id. Всем спасибо:)

if (!isset($_COOKIE['visitorid'])) { $visitorid = md5(uniqid(rand(),25)); setcookie("visitorid", $visitorid, 0x6FFFFFFF);
} else    $visitorid = $_COOKIE['visitorid'];